# How to correctly use "time" input element?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that renders the following html:

```
        <input
          type="time"
          step="1"
          value={this.state.time}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Time"
          onChange={(ev) => {this.setState({time:ev.target.value})}
        />
```

This "sort of" works, but the problem is that I can't type double digit numbers in the input field. Let's say I want to type 00:23:00. I start out with a time field that looks like this:

00:00:00

next I click with the mouse on the middle pair of zeros. I push '2' on the keyboard. Now it will look like this:

00:02:00

However when I type '3' (no matter how fast I do this), what happens is my value looks like this:

00:03:00

while I would expect it to look like this:

00:23:00

If I remove the `value` attribute it all works as expected, but in that case I can't set a start value in my time field, which is rather annoying when editing existing content.

I guess the `setState` triggers a rerender of the component, making it behave weirdly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you introduce delaying  the calling of  setState in the onChange callback, does it work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself. I was converting the `00:00:00` string (or whatever value it sent back to the code) in an integer representing a timestamp. In the `value` attribute I converted that integer back to the `00:00:00` representation. That seemed to generated the behaviour I described. If I just store the string as-is all works as expected.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this would be so? For instance, aren't two equal strings equal?

Comment: (In my case, it turned out the strings weren't the same.)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in jsbin, but can not reproduce your problem.

Demo is here: http://jsbin.com/vujixe/edit?html,js,output

You can test it.

By the way, if you want to set a start value in your field, the commendatory method is `getInitState`, just like my code in jsbin.
Second, `setState` does trigger a rerender of the component.

Comment: Good point. I tried adding some stuff and changing the code to look more like mine, but I can't get it reproduced either. Must be a combination of things (this is an input field in a table, shown in a bootstrap modal) that causes this. Hard to reproduce indeed :/

Comment: I think I found the problem. My `onChange` method converts the string to a number of seconds. In my `value=` attribute I reconvert this, this seems to cause the behavior.

Comment: I don't see any inputs in that demo

Comment: Indeed. Seems that jsbin thing is editable by anyone and it has been overwritten by something completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem because I was also passing min and max attributes to the element, and changing one of those attribute values on the fly.

What it is that the HTML element implement has internal state (required to implement typing double digits); and that state is lost if the element is recreated.

So:

- It's OK if the thing is re-rendered (as a result of using setState)
- It's not OK if the thing is re-created (as a result of changing one of its parameter values)